# Finitely-generated vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a finitely-generated vector space and $\mathcal{U, Z, W} \subseteq \mathcal{V}$ subspaces of $\mathcal{V}$. 
> Suppose that $dim\mathcal{U}+dim\mathcal{Z}+dim\mathcal{W} > 2dim\mathcal{V}$. 
> Does it imply that $dim\mathcal{U}\cap dim\mathcal{Z}\cap dim\mathcal{W} \neq $ {0}?

I took some examples at $\mathbb{F^3}$ and the claim seems to be true. I know it must be that $dim\mathcal{V} - dim\mathcal{Z} < dim\mathcal{U} \cap dim\mathcal{W}$ but struggling to see how to proceed from that point.
I'd like to get some insights

Comment: You have $\dim V - \dim U + \dim V - \dim W < \dim Z$. Can you see how that helps?

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks